# In Joomla 2.5, How do I show only submenu items of one root Level item on all pages?

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, submenu

I'm using Joomla 2.5.8 and I would like to have a secondary menu on all pages of the site that shows just the submenu items of root menu item #2 from the main menu.

```
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4
 --- Show just the below items ---
       | Item 2-1 |
       | Item 2-2 |
       | Item 2-3 |
       | Item 2-4 |
```

I've tried creating another menu module and setting the start and end levels, but it only shows for pages that are part of root menu item.

I've also tried not setting the start and end level options and just use the template css to hide the item I don't want, but when I hide the root menu item I can't get the sub menu items to show.

I don't really want to make separate menu because if there are major menu type changes to the Main Menu I don't to have to make them twice.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a module I just made. It renders the submenu items from a menu item you choose.
Download the plugin here: [Download](http://www.multiupload.nl/7VXAKEK011)

In case you can't download or there is some problem, here are the plugin files:

PHP file (`mod_submenu.php`):

```
<ul class="menu">

    <?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    $m = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();

    $active = $m->getActive();
    $active_id = isset($active) ? $active->id : $m->getDefault()->id;
    $path   = isset($active) ? $active->tree : array();

    $menu = $m->getMenu();

    $parentId = $params->get("menuitem");
    foreach($menu as $item){
        if($item->level == 2 && $item->parent_id == $parentId){
            $class = 'item-'.$item->id;
            if ($item->id == $active_id) {
                $class .= ' current';
            }
            if (in_array($item->id, $path)) {
                $class .= ' active';
            }

            $flink = $item->link;
            if ((strpos($item->link, 'index.php?') === 0) && (strpos($item->link, 'Itemid=') === false)) {
                $item->flink = $item->link.'&Itemid='.$item->id;

                if (strcasecmp(substr($item->flink, 0, 4), 'http') && (strpos($item->flink, 'index.php?') !== false)) {
                    $item->flink = JRoute::_($item->flink, true, $item->params->get('secure'));
                }
                else {
                    $item->flink = JRoute::_($item->flink);
                }
            }
            echo "<li class='$class'><a href='$item->flink'>$item->title</a></li>";
        }
    }
    ?>

</ul>
```

XML File (`mod_submenu.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5.0" client="site" method="install">
<name>Show Submenu</name>
<author>Brian</author>
<creationDate>2012</creationDate>
<copyright></copyright>
<license>No license</license>
<authorEmail>No email</authorEmail> 
<authorUrl>No website</authorUrl> 
<version>1.0.0</version> 
<description>Showing a submenu</description>

<files>
    <filename module="mod_submenu">mod_submenu.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
</files>

<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field
            name="menuitem"
            type="menuitem"
            label="Choose the menuitem" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
</extension>
```

(Excuse the formatting, I still have to get used to SO)

And a blank index.html file. Place em all in a folder called `mod_submenu`, zip, install and configure it!

Configuration:

[image: Configuring the plugin]

Result:

[image: Show Submenu result]

Comment: Great Job Brian, really useful looking module.  Worth posting to the JED?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the absolute best method but it's all I can think of for the time being.

For the parent menu item (Item 2), set the type to "Text Separator". This will stop it being a proper menu item and will most likely (depending on the template) wrap  tags around the text.

Then open a CSS file that belongs to the template and add the following code:

```
span.classname {
    display:none;
}
```

Obvioucly you will need to change **"classname"** to whatever class is given to it. Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug will assist you with this.

Comment: I've been trying the display none route and since the submenu items are a ul within the root level li, the moment I do a display:none I can't bring back the submenu ul.  I like your idea of setting the menu item type to a text separator!  The only bit I haven't been able to hide well is the anchor of the root level so this may fix it.

Comment: This is one way but the side effect of this is that your urls to the pages on the next level will additionally include the text seperator alias.  Just worth considering.